# Output of history command in iTerm

Tags: macos, iterm

I am using 'iterm' as my terminal at macosx. But I don't see all my command I type when I do 'history' and I don't see my previous command (copy and paste) using the UP arrow key?

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Can you give us a repeatable example?

Comment: History is handled by your shell (most likely GNU bash), not by your terminal program.

Comment: I have same problem

Answer (score 12):

Check you home dir in iTerm.

```
$ cd ~
$ ls -la | grep .bash_history
```

If the above command found the file you can do the following command

```
$ cat .bash_history
```

This will show your history. Not in the exact same format as 'history' but it will do I think. Or you can search within your history with the shortcut `CTRL + r`. It will show something as `(reverse-i-search)`. Type your command you did earlier and it will return a result.

Note: Some terminals have a different shell. For instance zsh. If that's the case you need to search `.zsh_history`

Comment: Bear in mind that if you use a bash alternative, you'll need to use it's history equivalent e.g. with ZSH, replace `.bash_history` with `.zsh_history`.

Comment: Give that man a Nobel Peace Prize.

Answer (score 2):

I likely missed you on this as it's been a while.  Leaving this here to help anyone else who may come along.  I had this same issue after I had just switched to MacOS.  When i type 'history', it would only give ~15 items and the up/down wouldn't work.  I recommend switching to bash.  The command to do this is `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

Additionally, I added these lines to my .bash_profile:

```
export SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0
#export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "HISTSIZE=10000
HISTSIZE=10000
HISTFILESIZE=20000
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
shopt -s histappend
```

Other things to check are the permissions for .bash_history file.  After i made these changes, my history problems have now been fixed.  Not all of these are needed to fix your history issues.  There are some other posts that say how to move combine both your zsh and bash history.  I would recommend doing that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem for a long time. I tried everything but Magic, not being myself a magician. Finally, I said to myself that it could last forever because having my history in the Toolbelt is a time saving, and I began looking systematically everywhere, even in Magic.
*Preferences > Magic > Save copy/paste and command history to disk*
was the solution I believe you are looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).